# trying to fetch datas from express.js using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, express

I am trying to build an application with backbone.js and express.js. I have an issue to return the values from express to backbone. I had the same problem with a simple Curl request (i could display req.params on the server side but impossible to get it on the client side, even using JSON.stringify() on it).

I did the same code with a simple echo json_ecode() in php and it works well...

Here is the code of a simple test on the server side:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/user/:id/:pass', function(req, res){
res.status(200);
res.send({"id": "1"});
});
```

On the client side, i don't get any of the success or error callaback...

```
 var U1 = new User();
    U1.fetch({
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('User fetched.'); 
            },
            error: function(model, error) {
              console.log('user Error: '+error);
            }
    });
```

What is wrong with my answer on express.js ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't really understand the question. How does backbone send a request to /user/joe/123 ? The express part looks fine to me. assuming you are actually requesting that resource.

Comment: Using the fetch method just above; it launch a GET request to "http://localhost:3000/user/:a/:b". With the same code on the client side, if i manage the server side with php it works.

Comment: Running "curl --verbose --raw --url http://localhost:3000/user/1/2" on your code does return a valid JSON object. What did you get when you ran curl on it?

Comment: Hi, Here is the result: 
curl --verbose --raw --url localhost:3000/user/1/2
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> GET /user/1/2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 15
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{
  "id": "1"
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
}

Comment: Interesting... If i change the route for "http://localhost:3000/user" (without the arguments) and i catch it with express, i go to the error backbone callback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution by adding `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in my express route.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the User model sets it's url to the same /user/login/password then it should work, see: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url Did you already create a url method on the User model?

I posted a couple articles on backbone.js and express ... http://www.pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/29/backbone-js-models-views-collections-to-present-api-data/ backbone example using API data from express app: http://pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/

Comment: Hi, yes here is the initialize method of my User model:
`initialize : function() {
                console.log('User Constructor...');
                this.url = "http://localhost:3000/user/"+this.get('a)+'/'+this.get('b');
            }`

Your articles seems very interesting ! I am going to work on it !